# Why am I getting a NullPointerException when I press "New Game"?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am working on the controller to make the Sudoku game. When you run my SudokuMain.java file, and click "File" at the top of the page and then select "New Game", I get the exception:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

I have an ActionListener for the "New Game" to create a JDialog object titled "Create Board", and prompts the user to enter the "Rows per region" and "Columns per region" and press "Create Board", or to press "Cancel" and do away with it.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I feel the issue lies in the inner class MenuAtTop. Any help is appreciated!

```
// Allow short name access to following classes
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SudokuMain extends JComponent {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SudokuMain();
  }

  private SudokuBase board;
  private SudokuView view;

  private JFrame win;
  private JPanel center;
  private JPanel west;
  private JPanel east;
  private JPanel cells;

  private final Dialog1 setWin1;

  public SudokuMain() {

   // start game
   view = new SudokuView(makeBoard());
   board = makeBoard();

   win = new JFrame("Sudoku");
   center = new JPanel();
   west = new JPanel();
   east = new JPanel();

   // "player" cells for current Sudoku board
   cells = new SetSymbols(view);
   // the 1st set-up window
   setWin1 = new Dialog1(this, "New Game", true);

   // create menu bar
   MenuAtTop menuBar = new MenuAtTop(this);
   win.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

   win.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   view.setSelected(1, 1);
   west.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   east.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   center.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

   west.add(cells);
   east.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   center.add(west);
    center.add(east);

   win.add(center);

   win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
   win.pack();
   win.setVisible(true);

 }

class SudokuControlButton extends JPanel {

  private int row;
  private int col;

  // row of selected cell
  private int selRow;
  // column of selected cell
  private int selCol;

  // the value that corresponds with the desired symbol
  private int value;

  /**
   * Constructs SudokuControlButton object; the graphic "button"
   * to control the board.
   */
  public SudokuControlButton(final SudokuView view) {

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
    setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    //value = 0;

    addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {

      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        selRow = view.getSelectedRow();
        selCol = view.getSelectedColumn();

        if(!board.isGiven(selRow, selCol)) {
          board.setValue(selRow, selCol, value);

        view.repaint();
        } else {  // have system beep sound
          getToolkit().beep();
        }

        repaint();
      }

      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
        // set to "highlighted" color
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        repaint();
      }

      public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
        // set to default color
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        repaint();
      }

      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        // set to "active" color
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        repaint();
      }

      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
      }

    });
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    switch(value) {
      case 0:
      drawSymbol(g, 0);
      break;
    case 1:
      drawSymbol(g, 1);
      break;
    case 2:
      drawSymbol(g, 2);
      break;
    case 3:
      drawSymbol(g, 3);
      break;
    case 4:
      drawSymbol(g, 4);
      break;
    case 5:
      drawSymbol(g, 5);
      break;
    case 6:
      drawSymbol(g, 6);
      break;
    case 7:
      drawSymbol(g, 7);
      break;
    case 8:
      drawSymbol(g, 8);
      break;
    case 9:
      drawSymbol(g, 9);
      break;
    case 10:
      drawSymbol(g, 10);
      break;
    case 11:
      drawSymbol(g, 11);
      break;
    case 12:
      drawSymbol(g, 12);
      break;
  }

}

/**
 * This method draws the symbol that corresponds with 
 * the specified value (0-12).
 * 
 * @param g The drawing mechanism.
 * @param value The specified value.
 */
public void drawSymbol(Graphics g, int value) {

  if(value < 0 || value > 12) {
    String msg = "Value cannot be less than 1 or greater than 12.";
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
  }

  // enable drawing with "thick" lines
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
  g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));

  switch(value) {
    case 0:
      // draw borders
      g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
      break;
    case 1:
      // draw borders
      g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
      // draw symbol
      g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 45);
      break;
    case 2:
      // draw borders
      g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
      // draw symbol
      g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 45);
      g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 45);
      break;
    case 3:
      // draw borders
      g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
      // draw symbol
      g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 45);
      g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 45);
      g2.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 45);
      break;
    case 4:
      // draw borders
      g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
      // draw symbol
      g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 45);
      g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 45);
      g2.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 45);
      g2.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 45);
      break;
    case 5:
      // draw borders
      g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
      // draw symbol
      g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 45);
      g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 45);
      g2.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 45);
      g2.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 45);
      g2.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 45);
      break;
    case 6:
      // draw borders
      g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
      // draw symbol
      g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 45);
      g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 45);
      g2.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 45);
      g2.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 45);
      g2.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 45);
      g2.drawLine(30, 5, 30, 45);
      break;
    case 7:
      // draw borders
      g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
      // draw symbol
      g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 20);
      g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 20);
      g2.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 20);
      g2.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 20);
      g2.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 20);
      g2.drawLine(30, 5, 30, 20);
      g2.drawLine(5, 30, 5, 45);
      break;
    case 8:
      // draw borders
      g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
      // draw symbol
      g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 20);
      g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 20);
      g2.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 20);
      g2.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 20);
      g2.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 20);
      g2.drawLine(30, 5, 30, 20);
      g2.drawLine(5, 30, 5, 45);
      g2.drawLine(10, 30, 10, 45);
      break;
    case 9:
      // draw borders
      g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
      // draw symbol
      g2.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 20);
      g2.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 20);
      g2.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 20);
      g2.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 20);
      g2.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 20);
      g2.drawLine(30, 5, 30, 20);
      g2.drawLine(5, 30, 5, 45);
      g2.drawLine(10, 30, 10, 45);
      g2.drawLine(15, 30, 15, 45);
      break;
    case 10:
      // draw borders
      g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
      // draw symbol
      g.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 20);
      g.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 20);
      g.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 20);
      g.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 20);
      g.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 20);
      g.drawLine(30, 5, 30, 20);
      g.drawLine(5, 30, 5, 45);
      g.drawLine(10, 30, 10, 45);
      g.drawLine(15, 30, 15, 45);
      g.drawLine(20, 30, 20, 45);
      break;
    case 11:
      // draw borders
      g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
      // draw symbol
      g.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 20);
      g.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 20);
      g.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 20);
      g.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 20);
      g.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 20);
      g.drawLine(30, 5, 30, 20);
      g.drawLine(5, 30, 5, 45);
      g.drawLine(10, 30, 10, 45);
      g.drawLine(15, 30, 15, 45);
      g.drawLine(20, 30, 20, 45);
      g.drawLine(25, 30, 25, 45);
      break;
    case 12:
      // draw borders
      g.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
      // draw symbol
      g.drawLine(5, 5, 5, 20);
      g.drawLine(10, 5, 10, 20);
      g.drawLine(15, 5, 15, 20);
      g.drawLine(20, 5, 20, 20);
      g.drawLine(25, 5, 25, 20);
      g.drawLine(30, 5, 30, 20);
      g.drawLine(5, 30, 5, 45);
      g.drawLine(10, 30, 10, 45);
      g.drawLine(15, 30, 15, 45);
      g.drawLine(20, 30, 20, 45);
      g.drawLine(25, 30, 25, 45);
      g.drawLine(30, 30, 30, 45);
      break;
    }

  }

 }

class MenuAtTop extends JMenuBar implements ActionListener{

  private SudokuMain main;

  private JMenu fileMenu;
  private JMenuItem newGame;

  private JDialog createNewWin; 

  public MenuAtTop(final SudokuMain m) {

    fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    add(fileMenu);

    newGame = new JMenuItem("New Game");
    newGame.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N,
                                                  ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    fileMenu.add(newGame);
    newGame.addActionListener(this);

  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    setEnabled(false);
    createNewWin = new Dialog1(main, "Create New Board", true);
  }

}

class Dialog1 extends JDialog {

  private JTextField rows;
  private JTextField cols;
  private JButton createBoard; 
  private JButton cancel;
  private JLabel rowLabel;
  private JLabel colLabel;
  private JLabel errorMes;


  private JPanel center;
  private JPanel north;
  private JDialog setUpWin2;

  /**
   * Constructs Dialog1 object.
   * 
   * @param win The window containing the dialog box.
   * @param header The title of dialog box.
   * @param modal Whether dialog box is modal or not.
   */
  public Dialog1(final SudokuMain win, String header, boolean modal) {
    // call superclass constructor
    super();

    // instantiate and bind to references
    rows = new JTextField(2);
    cols = new JTextField(2);
    createBoard = new JButton("Create Board");
    cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    rowLabel = new JLabel("Rows per region: ");
    colLabel = new JLabel("Columns per region: ");
    errorMes = new JLabel();

    north = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    center = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

    // set characteristics
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle(header);
    setModal(modal);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // set characteristics of error message
    errorMes.setForeground(Color.RED);
    errorMes.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 12));
    errorMes.setVisible(false);

    cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setVisible(false);
      }
    });

    createBoard.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int newRows;
        int newCols;
        int newSize;

        try{
          newRows = Integer.parseInt(rows.getText());
          newCols = Integer.parseInt(cols.getText());
        } catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
          newRows = 0;
          newCols = 0;
        }

        newSize = newRows * newCols;
        // input validation
        if(newSize <= 0 && newSize > 12) {
          errorMes.setText("Rows times columns cannot be greater than 12!");
          errorMes.setVisible(true);
          pack();

        } else{ // valid input
          errorMes.setVisible(false);
          setVisible(false);
          setUpWin2 = new Dialog2(win, "New Sudoku", newRows, newCols, true);
        }
      }});


    // place error message in the center
    center.add(errorMes);

    // place labels for rows and columns at the top 
    north.add(rowLabel);
    north.add(rows);
    north.add(colLabel);
    north.add(cols);

    add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    pack();

    if(!win.win.isVisible()) {
      dispose();
    }

  }
}

class Dialog2 extends JDialog {

  private SudokuView view;

  private JPanel panel;
  private JPanel northPanel;
  private JPanel cells;

  private JButton setGivens; 
  private JButton cancel;

  /**
   * Constructs Dialog2 object.
   * 
   * @param win The window containing the dialog box.
   * @param header The title of the dialog box.
   * @param rows the rows to the new SudokuBoard to be constructed in the dialog box
   * @param cols the columns to the new SudokuBoard to be constructed in the dialog box
   * @param modal boolean value for whether the box is modal or not
   */
  public Dialog2(final SudokuMain mainWin, String header, int rows, int cols,
                 boolean modal) {
    // call superclass constructor
    super();

    // instantiate and bind to references
    view = new SudokuView(new SudokuBoard(rows, cols));
    panel = new JPanel();
    northPanel = new JPanel();
    setGivens = new JButton("Set Givens");
    cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
    cells = new SetSymbols(view);

    // set up characteristics 
    setTitle(header);
    setModal(modal);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    northPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());


    setGivens.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // set "given" cells
        makeBoard().fixGivens();

        // have window refer to new board
        west.remove(mainWin.view);
        mainWin.east.remove(mainWin.cells);

        mainWin.view = view;
        mainWin.cells = cells;

        mainWin.west.add(mainWin.view);
        mainWin.east.add(mainWin.cells);

        setVisible(false);

      }});

    cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setVisible(false);
    }});

    // place buttons at the top
    northPanel.add(setGivens);
    northPanel.add(cancel);

    panel.add(view, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    add(panel);
    add(cells);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);

  }

}

class SetSymbols extends JPanel {

// temporary board to help create graphic "buttons"
private SudokuBoard tempBd;

/**
 * Constructs SetSymbols object.
 * @param view The SudokuView object for SetSymbols.
 */
public SetSymbols(final SudokuView view) {
  // instantiate and bind to reference
  tempBd = new SudokuBoard(1, board.getBoardSize() + 1);

  setLayout(new GridLayout((tempBd.getBoardSize())/2 + 1, 2));

  for(int colCell = 0; colCell < tempBd.getBoardSize(); colCell++) {

    // cannot be changed after set/instantiated
    final int value = colCell;
    final JPanel cell = new JPanel();
    final Color defaultColor = cell.getBackground();

    // set characteristics
    cell.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    // set value for each graphic "button"
    tempBd.setValue(0, colCell, colCell);
    // add the appropriate symbol to each graphic "button"
    cell.add(view.new SudokuCell(0, colCell, tempBd));

    cell.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
      // whether inside graphic "button" or not
      boolean insideCell;

      public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int selRow = view.getSelectedRow();
        int selCol = view.getSelectedColumn();

        if(!board.isGiven(selRow, selCol)) {
          board.setValue(selRow, selCol, value);

          view.repaint();
        }
        else {  // have system beep sound
          cell.getToolkit().beep();
        }

      }

      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        insideCell = true;
        // set to "highlighted" color
        cell.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        view.repaint();
      }

      public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        insideCell = false;
        // set to default color
        cell.setBackground(defaultColor);

        view.repaint();
      }

      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // set to "active" color
        cell.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

        view.repaint();
      }

      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if(insideCell) {
          cell.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        }
        else {  // outside of symbol's cell
          cell.setBackground(defaultColor);
        }

        view.repaint();
      }
    });

    // add graphic "button"
    add(cell);

  }

  // handle possible "empty" graphic "button"
  if(tempBd.getBoardSize() % 2 != 0) {
    JPanel empty = new JPanel();
    empty.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    empty.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    add(empty);
   }

   }

  }

  public static SudokuBase makeBoard() {
    SudokuBase board = new SudokuBoard(2, 3);
    board.setValue(0, 3, 6);
    board.setValue(0, 5, 1);
    board.setValue(1, 2, 4);
    board.setValue(1, 4, 5);
    board.setValue(1, 5, 3);
    board.setValue(2, 3, 3);
    board.setValue(3, 2, 6);
    board.setValue(4, 0, 2);
    board.setValue(4, 1, 3);
    board.setValue(4, 3, 1);
    board.setValue(5, 0, 6);
    board.setValue(5, 2, 1);
    board.fixGivens();
    return board;
  }

}
```

Comment: Q: "I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong..." A: You're not using a debugger.  Eclipse, Netbeans and even the command-line JDK all have debuggers that let you trace your code, set breakpoints, examine variables ... and get stack tracebacks showing the exact line (and, usually, exact variable) that's failing.  STRONG SUGGESTION: Use an IDE (like Eclipse) and familiarize yourself with its debugger!  IMHO...

Comment: Which line causes the NPE? Please post the *full* stacktrace so that we can help you. I also agree with @paulsm4 that you should learn how to use an IDE (such as Netbeans, Eclipse, or IntelliJ) and its built-in debugger. Learning how to debug code is an essential tool for every programmer.

Comment: You should post something a little longer. This is too concise...Seriously though, welcome to SO.  Here, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).  You're going to want to post a much more concise example.  If you ever have an error, print the stack trace.  Also, SO is no a debugging service, you have to try that on your own.  If you're still stuck post what you tried, and we'll try to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the variable `main` before it is given a value. Perhaps you meant to initialize it to the parameter in the MenuAtTop constructor, eg `main = m;`?

Comment: You should mark it as the correct answer for future visitors. Glad the problem is fixed.

Comment: thanks, that removed the NullPointerException. now, when i click "New Game" under "File", nothing occurs. this should instantiate a "Dialog1" object (basically a JDialog) titled "Create Board", and prompts the user to enter the "Rows per region" and "Columns per region" and then press "Create Board", or to press "Cancel" and do away with it. am i missing a SudokuMain field in the "Dialog1" clas?...

Comment: Try calling the `setVisible(boolean)` method of your dialog, as in `createNewWin.setVisible(true);` after you instantiate it. JDialog inherits from [Dialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setVisible%28boolean%29).

Comment: Thank you again! That was it. So are JDialog objects "setVisible(false)" by default?

Comment: In general with AWT and Swing components, that is true. I guess it's so that you can create them before actually using them.